# How to use Hungarian characters as a key in properties file with ResourceBundle in JAVA?

Tags: java, utf-8, properties, character-encoding, resourcebundle

I have a properties file where i got letters as keys and some integer value. Something like this:

```
a=1
b=2
c=5
...
```

Everything works but when I use Hungarian letters as keys (for example: "ő" or "ű") I got the following exception: "Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key ő."
I want something like that:

```
ő=7
```

I guess my properties file's encoding isn't UTF-8 but how can I change it?

Comment: Win7, normal windows application.

Comment: I've heard that the MS-Editor supports save as utf-8. To tired to test right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `\u0151=7` instead of `ő=7`in the *.properties* file? 
(For other characters please see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex or some other encoding table).

And to answer your encoding question - please try to use Notepad++. You can save/convert various char encodings with it.